# alarm when active sessions are 0 for 10 mins

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, tableau-api, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to run an AWS alarm when the Tableau action sessions are 0 for 10 mins. However, I am not sure what evaluation_period and periods I should be using. I tried 2 and 300 but it did not run the alarm when needed.

```
module "my_alarm" {
...
  comparison_operator       = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  metric_name               = "ActiveSessions"
  namespace                 = "TableauServer"
  period                    = "300"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = "0"
}
```

Comment: Well, 300 is in seconds, so it's five minutes. So you probably need 600.

Comment: and what would the evaluation period be then? 1? @MarkoE

Comment: Hm, I might have jumped to conclusion to fast, sorry. I think the current setup means that the metric will be evaluated 2 times in a period of 5 minutes. I think you might need this as well: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm#datapoints_to_alarm.

Comment: and what would be the values then? @MarkoE

Comment: Well, I think 1 period of 600 seconds. But can the threshold be breached only at the end of 10 minutes or it can happen anywhere in between?

Comment: i would say anywhere in between I think. I would want the alarm to run whenever there is no activity for any consecutive 10 mins. @MarkoE

Comment: Hm, well maybe you can set it to one minute and more evaluation periods. And probably set `datapoints_to_alarm` to 1 as well.